# Creating an `std::env::Args` iterator for testing

Tags: unit-testing, rust, parameter-passing

Is there a way in Rust to create a `std::env::Args` from a `Vec<String>` in order to use it in a `#[test]` function?

I wish to test a function that gets a `std::env::Args` as an argument, but I don't know how to create such an object with a list of arguments I supply for the test.

I wasn't able to figure this one out from the docs, the source nor from Google searches.

Comment: Could you change the function so that it takes a generic `I: Iterator<Item = String>` instead? That's much easier to mock up.

Comment: @trentcl, nice workaround, but is this idiomatic Rust? Must I forgo the clear intent of *this function expects  to get command line arguments* in favor of *this function expects some generic iterator that yields strings* for it to be testable?

Comment: Being generic in what you accept is the way to go. The function name can indicate the intent, but using generic input types keeps the function flexible.

Comment: Yes? If the contract of the function is "takes command line arguments", the only *correct* way to test it is to pass command line arguments. You have to relax the contract to be able to test it with arbitrary strings. (But I should have mentioned `IntoIterator` instead of `Iterator`, since that will work with `Vec`.)

Comment: Aside, I tend to agree with loganfsmyth, but if for some reason it is important to enforce "give me command line arguments" on the caller, you can wrap the generic function and its tests in a module and only expose a `pub fn` that takes `Args` exactly (and calls the generic version to do the work). Although at that point maybe you might as well call `std::env::args()` yourself and take no arguments at all.

Answer (score 13):

The fields of [`std::env::Args`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/struct.Args.html) are not documented, and there doesn't appear to be a public function to create one with custom fields. So, you're outta luck there.

But since it's just "*An iterator over the arguments of a process, yielding a `String` value for each argument*" your functions can take a `String` iterator or `Vec` without any loss of functionality or type safety. Since it's just a list of `String`s, it doesn't make much sense to arbitrarily limit your functions to strings which happen to come from the command line.

Looking through [Rust's own tests](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/search?p=1&q=%22env%3A%3AArgs%22&type=&utf8=%E2%9C%93), that's just what they do. There's a lot of `let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();`

There's even [an example in `rustbuild`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/adbce60d6f131e5b3789f01417dedb05e4489898/src/bootstrap/bin/main.rs) where they strip off the name of the program and just feed the list of arguments.

```
use std::env;

use bootstrap::{Config, Build};

fn main() {
    let args = env::args().skip(1).collect::<Vec<_>>();
    let config = Config::parse(&args);
    Build::new(config).build();
}
```

And [`bootstrap::Config::parse()`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/bootstrap/config.rs#L300) looks like so:

```
impl Config {
    pub fn parse(args: &[String]) -> Config {
        let flags = Flags::parse(&args);
        ...
```

I'm not a Rust expert, but that seems to be how the Rust folks handle the problem.

Answer (score 6):

[@Schwern's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47441713/155423) is good and it led me to this simpler version. Since `std::env::Args` implements `Iterator` with `Item = String` you can do this:

```rust
use std::env;

fn parse<T>(args: T)
where
    T: Iterator<Item = String>,
{
    for arg in args {
        // arg: String
        print!("{}", arg);
    }
}

fn main() {
    parse(env::args());
}
```

To test, you provide `parse` with an iterator over `String`:

```rust
#[test]
fn test_parse() {
   let args = ["arg1", "arg2"].iter().map(|s| s.to_string());
   parse(args);
}
```

Comment: FWIW, this is already mentioned in the existing answer: "your functions can take a `String` iterator".

Comment: Using `IntoIterator` will probably lead to easier code at some point (`fn parse(args: impl IntoIterator<Item = String>)`). To be extremely flexible, accept anything that can be treated as a `&str` (`fn parse(args: impl IntoIterator<Item = impl AsRef<str>>)`) or perhaps `Into<String>`.

Answer (score 0):

I've wrote a little macro to make this easier, based on [@Rossman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54594023/7664765) (and therefore also based on [@Schwern's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47441713/155423); thanks go to both):

```rust
macro_rules! make_string_iter {
    ($($element: expr), *) => {
        {
            let mut v = Vec::new();
            $( v.push(String::from($element)); )*
            v.into_iter()
        }
    };
}
```

It can be used in that way:

```rust
macro_rules! make_string_iter {
    ($($element: expr), *) => {
        {
            let mut v = Vec::new();
            $( v.push(String::from($element)); )*
            v.into_iter()
        }
    };
}

// We're using this function to test our macro
fn print_args<T: Iterator<Item = String>>(args: T) {
    for item in args {
        println!("{}", item);
    }
}

fn main() {

    // Prints a, b and c
    print_args(make_string_iter!("a", "b", "c"))
}
```

Or try it out on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=28b445e597840c5750d3d5ca024108db).

I'm not (yet) an expert in rust, any suggestions are highly welcome :)